# Workerpool says my workers are terminated when I try to execute a function

Tags: node.js, node-worker-threads, worker-pool

I'm trying to add workers to my Node.JS application so that I can run jobs after an endpoint gets hit and eventually process files.

I am trying to use the npm package [workerpool](https://www.npmjs.com/package/workerpool) but when I call my workerpool to execute a function I get the following error:
`Error running analysis:  Error: Worker is terminated`

I setup my workerpool in **worker.ts**

```
import workerpool from "workerpool"

export const setupWorkers = async () => {
  try {
    const filepath = __dirname + "/analysisWorker.ts"

    const pool = workerpool.pool(filepath, {
      minWorkers: 2,
      maxWorkers: 4,
      maxQueueSize: 20,
      workerType: "thread",
      emitStdStreams: true,
    })

    console.log(`Total workers: ${pool.stats().totalWorkers}`)
    return pool
  } catch (err) {
    console.error("Error when setting up workers")
  }
}
```

the filepath points to my **analysisWorker.ts** file which only has this in it:

```
import workerpool from "workerpool"

function runAnalysis() {
  console.log("job started")
  return 1000
}

// NOTE: I have tried removing this aswel
workerpool.worker({
  runAnalysis: runAnalysis,
})
```

I then setup my workers in my **app.ts** file like so:

```
...
app.use(cookieParser("test_123"))
app.use(express.json())
app.use(cors())

const startApp = async () => {
  // Setup workers
  const workerpool = await setupWorkers()

  // Attach workerpool to app
  app.set("workerpool", workerpool)

  // Connect to database
  await connect()

  // Setup routes
  routes(app)

  // Error handling
  app.use(errorHandler)

  app.listen(PORT, async () => {
    console.log(
      `Server started on port ${PORT} in ${process.env.NODE_ENV} mode`
    )
  })
}

startApp()
```

When I start the app I get the expected console log of "Total workers: 2" in my terminal.
Note I am also using `app.set` to set the workerpool so I can use it in the rest of my project.

Finally, in my controller file **productController.ts**, I have a product class with the following function which is ran when I hit `localhost:3000/products` with a POST.

```
  public async create(req: Request, res: Response, next: NextFunction) {
    const product = await productService.addProduct(req.body.name)
    const workerpool = req.app.get("workerpool")
    workerpool
      .exec("runAnalysis")
      .then((result: number) => {
        console.log("result: ", result)
      })
      .catch((err: Error) => {
        console.error("Error running analysis: ", err)
      })
    console.log(workerpool.stats().totalWorkers)

    res.send({ status: "OK", data: product, count: 1 })
  }
```

Notice the `catch` block is what is producing the error above, however the `console.log` directly after it prints **2** to the terminal, which means I still have active workers.

Can anyone see what I am doing wrong, I have tried looking at the docs and can't figure out why my workers are terminated but still active.